# Create function that returns the value of a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

If someone can help me figure out what is wrong with this code I'll be really grateful. I'm trying to make a function `getIth(int n)` that returns the value of `node n` in the list, but it is not working and I don't know why.

node.h
    `template<typename T>`

```
class Node
{
    public:

        T nValue;
        Node<T> *next;
        Node<T> *before;

        Node(T a)
        {
            nValue = a;
        }                                                                                                                
};
```

linked_list.h

```
#include "node.h"                                                                                                                                                                                           

#ifndef NULL
#define NULL = 0
#endif

template <typename T>

class LinkedList
{
    private:

       Node<T> *head;
       Node<T> *last;

    public:
        LinkedList()
        {
            T value = -1;
            head = new Node<T>(value);
            head->next = NULL;

            last = new Node<T>(value);
            last->before = NULL;
        }

        T getIth(int n)
        {
            int contador = 0;
            T value = -1;
            Node<T> *tempNode = new Node<T>(value);
            tempNode = last;

            while(tempNode->next != NULL)
            {
                contador = contador + 1;

                if(contador == n)
                {
                    value = tempNode->nValue;
                }

                tempNode->next = tempNode;
            }

            return value; 
       }
}
```

Comment: Your last and head are not connected. You are not initializing last->next.

Comment: Also this leaks memory. Node<T> *tempNode = new Node<T>(value);
tempNode = last;

Comment: And at the end of the statements of the `if(contador == n)`-block you should add a `break`. Going further does not make sense. Or you could also put a `return value;` in there. But, there are people who do not like multiple return paths within one routine if these do not give huge advantages (as exiting from multiple loop levels).

Comment: `double value_of_linked_list() { return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();  }`

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot of things wrong with your code, but the biggest error is here

```
T getIth(int n){
    ...
    while (tempNode->next != NULL)
    {
        ...
        tempNode->next = tempNode;
    }
}
```

You should do it the other way around

```
T getIth(int n){
    ...
    while (tempNode->next != NULL)
    {
        ...
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
}
```

Remember you are trying to make `tempNode` point to the next node, not make the next node point to `tempNode`.

Another error is here

```
Node<T> *tempNode = new Node<T>(value);
tempNode = last;
```

First you make `tempNode` point to a new node, and then you make `tempNode` point to `last`. Obivously that's a waste of time (and memory). Just make `tempNode` point to `last`, you don't need a new node at all.

```
Node<T> *tempNode = last;
```

Fix those errors and you'll be closer but I think there might be a lot more bugs to fix.

Comment: The real problem here is that he's not using a std::list, not that he failed at using his raw pointers.